# Locale-unaware %DATE% and %TIME% in batch files?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, batch, localization

The `%DATE%` and `%TIME%` environment variables provide the current date and time on Windows machines on the command line and inside a batch file.

Sadly, those values are locale-aware! Meaning that, say, on a German machine, you will get

```
26.1.2011
```

instead of

```
2011-26-01
```

this screws up sorting if you want to use this variable in a file name.

Is there any easy way to get hold of a locale-unaware `YYYY-MM-DD` date string in a Windows batch file?

For the moment, I am working with this rather kludgy workaround:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=. " %%i in ('date /t') do set date=%%k-%%j-%%i
echo %date%
```

but this is now German locale specific - obviously, a completely independent solution would be *much* nicer.

The OS in question is Server 2008. I would much prefer not using a third party tool, if at all possible.

Answer (score 25):

There were a few attempts ([Rob van der Woude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech.php#Time) had something), but nothing really worked across all locales. However, you can get the current time in a easily-parseable format via

```
wmic os get LocalDateTime
```

The following gets you at least UTC already:

```
@echo off
rem Get the time from WMI - at least that's a format we can work with
set X=
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined X set X=%%x
echo.%X%

rem dissect into parts
set DATE.YEAR=%X:~0,4%
set DATE.MONTH=%X:~4,2%
set DATE.DAY=%X:~6,2%
set DATE.HOUR=%X:~8,2%
set DATE.MINUTE=%X:~10,2%
set DATE.SECOND=%X:~12,2%
set DATE.FRACTIONS=%X:~15,6%
set DATE.OFFSET=%X:~21,4%

echo %DATE.YEAR%-%DATE.MONTH%-%DATE.DAY% %DATE.HOUR%:%DATE.MINUTE%:%DATE.SECOND%.%DATE.FRACTIONS%
```

However, you probably need to account for the time zone offset (unless it's for a log file, then I'd always use UTC) but that's nothing a bit of calculation cannot do :-)

Comment: Excellent, this looks exactly like what I need! Thank you.

Comment: For the record: `for /f %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime ^| findstr /b [0-9]') do @set X=%%x` is a tiny bit nicer. There's also a [more compact version available over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/203116/), namely in [that comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us#comment14652563_203116).

Comment: It's a bit hard finding and updating all old instances where you wrote something :). I'd probably use Win32_UTCTime and Win32_LocalTime by now.

Comment: really fantastic!

Comment: As @Tomalak says, the `findstr` solution is much better, as for my case, the original `for` (without the `skip`) iterates 3 times. Once for the word `"LocalDateTime"`, a second time for the actual date, and a third time for an empty value (maybe a line break?).

Comment: Note that this only works inside a `.bat` file. To paste it directly into a cmd window you need to replace each `%%` with `%`

Answer (score 14):

Here's a two-liner I've been using, which seems to work regardless of Windows version or local time settings:

```
FOR /f %%a in ('WMIC OS GET LocalDateTime ^| find "."') DO set DTS=%%a
set CUR_DATE=%DTS:~0,4%-%DTS:~4,2%-%DTS:~6,2%
```

This will set a variable called %CUR_DATE% in the following ISO standard format:

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

I tried making it a one-liner with &&, but it didn't seem to take, so I resorted to the two-line version. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use this trick to get UTC..

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('tzutil /g') do set CTZ=%%i
tzutil /s UTC
set UTC=
for /f  "skip=1 delims=" %%i in ('WMIC OS GET LocalDateTime') do if not defined UTC set UTC=%%i
tzutil /s "%CTZ%"
set UTC=%UTC:~0,4%-%UTC:~4,2%-%UTC:~6,3%T%UTC:~8,13%
echo %UTC%
```

However it does have the side effect of briefly changing the entire system to UTC. This is probably OK on a personal workstation, but not sure what the impact would be a large production server, which should probably be set to UTC anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to this problem:

```
@echo off

set curtime=
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('powershell -NoLogo -NonInteractive -OutputFormat Text -Command "[DateTime]::Now.ToString(\"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss\")"') do set curtime=%%x
echo %curtime%
```

Of course, the same as UTC time:

```
set curtime=
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('powershell -NoLogo -NonInteractive -OutputFormat Text -Command "[DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString(\"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssK\")"') do set curtime=%%x
echo %curtime%
```

You may play with formatting as much as you like, the output is stable independent from Windows of CurrentLocale (here is minimal knowledge of Powershell and .Net required).